# Package version management in Go 1.5

Tags: go

I'm getting my hands dirty with Go, and while I understand and appreciate the principle of *simplicity* that Go was built upon, I'd like to grasp the rationale behind forgoing a **built-in package versioning method** in their dependency-fetching tool `go get` and the `import` statement.

If I understand correctly, `go get` and `import` fetch the package from `HEAD` and they are unable to refer to a branch or a tag. While there are tools like [gopkg.in](http://labix.org/gopkg.in) that circumvent this limitation, the official toolchain:

1. Forces developers to create separate repos for major (breaking) versions of their products.
2. It doesn't allow consumers to downgrade between minor or micro versions in case bugs are found in newer ones.

Truth be told, things are not so easy because package versioning would require a strategy to deal with conflicting transitive dependencies, e.g. `X` depends on `A` and `B`, each of which depend on different versions of `C`.

Coming from a Java background, it does appear that this limitation poses some risks and problems, amongst others:

1. Product/package evolution and breakage of public APIs of 3rd party deps is unavoidable, therefore versioning must be a first-class citizen in the toolchain IMHO.
2. The *Git-repo-per-version* policy is highly inefficient:

   - The overall Git history of the package is lost or scattered across repos (merges between versions, backports, etc.)
   - Conflicts with transitive dependencies may still occur, and will go about undetected because the language nor the toolchain impose any semantics to allow detection in the first place.
3. Enterprise adoption may be hindered and development teams may shy away from the language, given that:

   - Always dragging in `HEAD` means that they can't control or freeze their 3rd party deps, leading to a potentially unpredictable end product.
   - May lack the manpower to keep their product constantly updated and tested with upstream's `HEAD` (not every company in the world is Google :)).

While I do understand that the latter risk can be – and must be – mitigated with Continuous Integration, it does not solve the underlying root of the problem.

What information am I missing? How do you deal with package upstream changes when deploying Go in an enterprise with limited manpower?

Comment: you can use vendored imports. By designing `go get` to pull from HEAD, it allows easier pulls of bugfixes and forces API developers to be more mindful of backwards-incompatible changes. That said, this is clearly an opinion-based question, which isn't on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I see. I've changed the wording to avoid opinion-based answers. If you could elaborate on vendor imports – or other tactics to deploy Go in the enterprise without having to deal with constant upstream changes, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is being addressed by [vendoring](https://golang.org/s/go15vendor) which is part of Go 1.5 as an experimental feature, it can be enabled if the go command is run with `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` in its environment, and will be a "full" feature in Go 1.6. Also see [Vendor Directories](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories).

The original discussion that led to the Go 1.5 Vedor Experiment can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/74zjMON9glU/4lWCRDCRZg0J).

The essence of vendoring is that you create a folder named `vendor`, and you put the exact version of the packages that your code relies on. Code inside the `vendor` folder is only importable by the code in the directory tree rooted at the parent of `vendor`, and you can import packages from `vendor` with an import path as if `vendor` would be the `workspace/src` folder (that is, with an import path that omits the prefix up to and including the vendor element).

Example:

```
/home/user/goworkspace/
    src/
        mymath/
            mymath.go
            vendor/
                github.com/somebob/math
                    math.go
```

In this example `github.com/somebob/math` is an external package used by `mymath` package (from `mymath.go`). It can be used from `mymath.go` if it is imported like:

```
import "github.com/somebob/math"
```

(And not as `import mymath/vendor/github.com/somebob/math` which would be bad.)

Answer (score 1):

While Go doesn't come with the standard package manager there are enough options to make builds reproducible (even in an enterprise with limited manpower).

1. Vendoring, which is described in another answer by @icza. This is almost complete equivalent of checking in versioned jar files in Java. This was very common approach with ant build tool before maven became popular. Actually vendoring is much better because you cannot lose source code.
2. This is slight variation of the first option. Instead of checking in vendored source code you can populate vendor folder during build by checking out predefined versions of the dependencies. There tools (e.g. glide) that automate this process.
3. Finally you can maintain predefined versions of all 3-rd party libraries in the internal repository and add it to GOPATH. This approach is described in detail in https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/go-in-a-monorepo/

Note that incompatible transitive dependencies are not specific to Go. They exist in Java (and most other languages) too, though Java has a mechanism to partially solve this problem by making programs more complex - class loaders. Note that Go will report all incompatibilities at compile time while in Java some of the incompatibilities are triggered only at run time (because of late linking).

Java toolchain doesn't have concept of versions. It is provided by the external tool - maven. I believe by the time Go becomes more mature and popular a similar standard dependency management tool will emerge.

Comment: My point was that Java didn't even make an attempt to solve 3rd party package sourcing within the standard toolkit. Java left a void that was filled by Maven + other Maven repository based tools, and Maven has gone on to become the de-facto tool for this. Conversely, Go did address 3rd party package sourcing within its toolset, so it looked like an omission not to think earlier about version or vendor management. Finally, when I mentioned transitive dependencies, I meant Maven's semantics for version addressing and conflict reporting at build time.

Comment: Sorry, but this wasn't very clear from your question. I can only guess that go toolchain lacks version support because it was never a problem for its authors (and many other people ;). As far as I know Maven doesn't report any version conflicts. It tries its best to resolve versions of transitive dependencies, though often you will have to explicitly specify them anyway.