# go lang version-able string normalization

Tags: go, unicode

I am working on a project where some strings are hashed. To make sure that I always get the right result I would like to normalize them before I hash them. ... and there is the Unicode norm package for that. So far so good.

I do not want to store the normalized form, already have the data stored in its raw from - that I assume the customer likes it. I would like years later if I am asked to calculate the hash to the same string I to get the same result. Now if the standard improves or there was a bug that was fixed using the latest version of the library will allow for a different result. I do not care if the previous result was not perfect - I just want the same one.

My question is: what might be a good way to enforce consistency - avoiding my own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the hash for the texts? That way you don't even have to normalize and calculate them when you need them.

If you can't or don't want to: you don't have to use the latest version of the normalization package. You can pick the current latest version (or any commit you choose), and put it in a vendor folder. And so you can use this "fixed" version years later too. For vendoring details, see [Package version management in Go 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775722/package-version-management-in-go-1-5/34775947#34775947).

Just think about it: if the [`norm`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm) package is changed (e.g. a bug is fixed) and produces a different output (normalized text), how else would you be able to get the "old" output without having the code that produces the old output? Only by having the old version of the `norm` package.

On the other hand, you said you need to calculate the hash to verify that the data was not tampered. If so, I don't see the purpose of normalization. You can just hash the text without normalization, if the original text is changed (e.g. it was "edited", but it wasn't really changed, just re-saved in normalized form), that can be taken as "tampered".

Comment: I do keep the hash, but I need to recalculate the hashes as form of validation that the data was not tampered with. I am aware of the vendors pattern, but I still would like to move forward, I just want to be able to call old version for old data. Maybe I am asking for too much.

Comment: @icze. Yes, I need the code that originally computed the normal form. And this is kind of my question - what could be a strategy for having that. Obviously staying forever on the same version will make sure that I do have the same result for this particular goal. But this is a small chunk of all I need to consider, moving forward is so often forced from other factors, that I believe I cannot afford that.

Comment: Why I need normalization is a very valid point. I am debating this with myself too. Since the project I am working is having so many aspects - the normalization in place will guarantee that semantically the same object will always produce the same hash (at least for the same version of the software). Not having such guarantee may or may not create limitations in other areas of the system that I would prefer to explore the options I have to ensure 1-1 before I disregard the potential risk of complications in other areas.