# Go - interface conversion [recovered] - error

Tags: go, glide-golang

The test logs show the following error

```
row 0 - got data of type graph.Node but wanted graph.Node
--- FAIL: TestAlls (0.84s)
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is graph.Node, not graph.Node [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: interface {} is graph.Node, not graph.Node
```

From the following code

```
nnn = graph.Node{}
nnn, ok = row[0].(graph.Node)
if !ok {
  log.Printf("row 0 - got data of type %T but wanted graph.Node", nnn)
}
neo4jNode := row[0].(graph.Node)
```

- Is it possible that there are two different types with the same name? (graph.Node)
- In which case, which folders should I clear out?
- What does [recovered] mean?

I am using glide install, go clean, go build, go test.

Comment: Most likely you have the `graph` package vendored (inside a `vendor` folder), and in one place you import the vendored, and in another you import the non-vendored version (or you have multiple vendored versions of it in multiple `vendor` folders). A vendored package is not equal / identical to the non-vendored version. See [Package version management in Go 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775722/package-version-management-in-go-1-5/34775947#34775947) about vendoring.

Comment: The issue may lie in your code or vendoring as @icza mentioned; however, your log statement is incorrect and probably confusing you even more. You are asserting `row[0]` as `graph.Node`, so of course `nnn` will be of that type. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/hvJlfb1FPe) is an example.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I was confused, and have corrected the example

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that there are two different types with the same name? (graph.Node)

Yes. If the code that produces the object (whatever is generating `rows`) references a *different copy of the same library*, the types will not match - for example, if you reference library `foo`, which has `graph` vendored, it will be referencing its vendored version, while you are referencing your own version. It's also possible to have two completely different packages (different import paths) both named `graph` but I'm assuming you've ruled this out.

> In which case, which folders should I clear out?

It's unfortunately not that simple - you need to look carefully at your dependencies. If you're importing a project as a library, and it has its own dependencies vendored, you're going to have a bad time. That's exactly why it's a bad practice to vendor dependencies in a library (dependencies should *only* be vendored for binaries).

> What does [recovered] mean?

It means a `panic` was [recovered](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics). This is done by the testing library to return accurate test results in the event of a test causing a panic.

Comment: Adrian, when you say _different copy of the same library_ do you mean a different _version_? `graph.Node` is defined in `github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver`. In `glide.lock` the version number is `2387cc1f01254d3a0055e034f5716278a1f420c7` - is that what defines the version? Coming from a java/jar background I find it strange to download dependencies in source code format - all part of working to understand the Go mindset. .. ..

Comment: Not necessarily a different version, it could be different copies of the same version, one vendored by one of your dependencies, one either vendored by you or just in your GOPATH.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback. I will need to gain more in-depth knowledge of glide & dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the problem was multiple glide.yaml (& vendor/) in the repository. The solution was to only have a root glide.yaml (& vendor/).